# (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) Mozilla Browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I added an event handler to handle a mousedown event in firefox but I get a `NS_error failure` message when this event is encountered, the error message is displayed on firefox but chrome handles the event properly.

Here is the section of code

```
document.getElementById("fancybox-close")
.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    c.video.currentTime = "00:00";
    document.getElementById("playr_video_curpos_" + c.video_id).innerHTML = c.parseTimeCode(c.video.currentTime);
}, false);
```

I attached the event listener to a close button on the video player, so when you click the close button the video is to be reset to `00:00` (Note: `c = this`).

As said earlier this works on chrome but on firefox I get this error message

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLVideoElement.currentTime]
```

Any idea why I get this message?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `currentTime` attribute takes a number, not a string. In this case, Chrome must do type coercion, while Firefox does not. For example:

```
c.video.currentTime = 0.0; // Seek to zero seconds
```

**References**

- [Mozilla source: nsIDOMHTMLMediaElement.idl](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/interfaces/html/nsIDOMHTMLMediaElement.idl)
- [Blink source: HTMLMediaElement.idl](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/blink/trunk/Source/core/html/HTMLMediaElement.idl)
- [intermittent failure in test_timeupdate_seek.html](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=596947)
- [HTML5 Audio and Video: Seeking through Media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Seeking_through_media)